# Copy HTML to clipboard

Tags: javascript

I use a simple third party library to copy something to clipboard.

The something is always some programming code. In these examples it is HTML and Python codes.

```
<button id="copy-code-sample-3" data-code-sample-id="3" data-clipboard-text="<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=&quot;en&quot;>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title></title>
  <link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; href=&quot;stylesheets/style.css&quot;></style>

  <script src=&quot;https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js&quot;></script>
  <script src=&quot;https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js&quot;></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>" class="code-sample-button">Copy (fail)</button>

<button id="copy-code-sample-1" data-code-sample-id="1" data-clipboard-text="from django import template
from code_sample.models import CodeSample
from django.utils.html import mark_safe
from general.const import CSS, SCRIPTS

register = template.Library()

class CodeSampleManager():
    def __init__(self, code_sample_obj: CodeSample):
        self.code_sample_obj = code_sample_obj

    def prepare_code(self):
        code = self.code_sample_obj.body
        breakpoints = self.code_sample_obj.breakpoints
        breakpoints = breakpoints.split(&quot;,&quot;)
        breakpoints = [int(bp) for bp in breakpoints]

        tmp = '<pre class=&quot;code&quot;>'

        lines = code.split(&quot;\r\n&quot;)
        counter = 1


        for line in lines:
            breakpoint = &quot;&quot;

            if counter in breakpoints:
                breakpoint = 'class=&quot;breakpoint&quot;'

            tmp += &quot;<code {}>{}</code>\n&quot;.format(breakpoint, line)
            counter += 1
        tmp += &quot;</pre>&quot;
        return tmp" class="code-sample-button">Copy (success)</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://milankyncl.github.io/jquery-copy-to-clipboard/jquery.copy-to-clipboard.js"></script>
```

In short: whatever is placed in data-clipboard-text attribute of a button, will be copied to the clipboard.

Please, press a Copy button in the example and insert into a text editor what there is in the clipboard.

Documentation to the third party library: https://milankyncl.github.io/jquery-copy-to-clipboard/

https://jsfiddle.net/Nonverbis/nzx7dvm8/12/

Copy (fail) button copies the contents of its data-clipboard-text but it consists only of whitespace characters and line breaks.

Morever, when I run this at my localhost, I get this error after clicking the fail button:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8000/draft/linux/install-os-ubuntu/stylesheets/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

The reason seems that HTML is considered to be a real HTML. The browser looks for sources, fails and sends the error. But for my purpose this is just a string.

[image]

Could you help me understand why this situation occurs and cope with the problem of copying HTML documents.

Comment: your jsfiddle is messed up - please post the necessary code right within your question.

Comment: Added the code to the question. But where can be a mess here? Three tags. Two buttons and inclusion of a third party library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8000/draft/linux/install-os-ubuntu/stylesheets/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Is self-explanatory i.e

`strict MIME checking is enabled` from the plugin so if you remove `link` and `script` tag then it will work because of security issue `MIME` check is good practices.

Comment: From what plugin should I remove strict MIME checking? 

As for removing a code line, I need it. This is a code sample. Visitors of the site will copy it, but without a line it will be just some garbage.